# Как совместить JSON_REMOVE и JSON_SEARCH в одном запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

У меня есть таблица test, в которой есть поле json с форматом данных JSON.
В этом поле лежит массив [2, 3, 4, 5].
Я хочу удалить из массива троечку. И успешно делаю это следующим запросом:

```
UPDATE test SET json = JSON_REMOVE(json, '$[1]') WHERE `id` = 2;
```

Но что, если я знаю, что в массиве есть элемент со значением 3, но не знаю его индекса?
Пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос:

```
UPDATE test SET json = JSON_REMOVE(
    json,
    '$[
        JSON_SEARCH(json, 'one', 3)
    ]'
) WHERE `id` = 2;
```

Получаю ошибку синтаксиса.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что я делаю не так?

Скобок и кавычек настолько много, что запрос потерял смысл; надо быть проще:

```
UPDATE test 
  SET json = JSON_REMOVE(json, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json, 'one', 3)))
  WHERE `id` = 2;
```

А если говорить более формально, то `JSON_SEARCH ()` и так возвращает путь, так что не нужно никаких дополнительной обработки значения прежде чем передать его `JSON_REMOVE ()`.

Замечания:

- `JSON_SEARCH ()` возвращает ответ как json-документ — строку в кавычках, поэтому можно использовать `JSON_UNQUOTE`, чтобы из убрать.
- В MySQL `JSON_SEARCH ()` не может искать не-строковые значения — это очевидный [баг](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233), хотя некоторые считают, что его просто надо задокументировать; в MariaDB данной проблемы нет.

Comment: Спасибо за участие! Что ж, по крайней мере этот запрос не выдает ошибку. Однако, в результате он присваивает полю json значение null. Вот сейчас кручу-верчу запросы, пробую вариации. Давайте пробовать вместе. (Один килочёрт, в документации синтаксис работы с типом данных json описан так вырвиглазно, что ничего понять нельзя...)

Comment: Кажется, разобрался. Похоже, дело в приведении типов. На запрос select JSON_SEARCH('[\"1\", \"2\", 3]', 'one', 3) as 'index' мне отвечают "index": null. На запрос select JSON_SEARCH('[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]', 'one', '3') as 'index' мне отвечают "index": "\"$[2]\"". Но на запрос select JSON_SEARCH('[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]', 'one', 3) as 'index' мне тоже отвечают  "index": "\"$[2]\"" !!! Похоже, мой следующий вопрос - как заставить функцию JSON_SEARCH понять что число это число...

Comment: @muturgan, поправил/дополнил ответ... думаю для mysql единственным решением будет реализовать логику работы с JSON на стороне sql-клиента... или поменять схему

Comment: Спасибо большое за уточнение с JSON_UNQUOTE, я этот момент как-то упустил

Comment: По поводу MariaDB и багов - я этот вопрос конечно не изучал специально, но я думал что раз она отпочковалась от мускула то она обречена просто вечно его догонять. А оказывается вон как!

Comment: А задумывалось все для следующего: есть таблица "новости" и таблица "группы новостей". И я хотел в одном столбце "групп" хранить массив с айдишниками новостей. терпеть не могу городить таблицы соответствий - это по-моему... нелаконично что ли. Но оказалось (ну вы то я думаю в курсе) что если в таблице соответствий прописать вторичные ключи, то сама база данных не даст создать ссылку на несуществующую новость. А для json я должен был бы это руками валидировать. Так что свое отношение к таблицам соответствия я поменял. Но все равно спасибо за науку - это совсем не лишнее знание)

Comment: кстати, было бы правильно, если бы вы дали еще ответ на это вопрос (вы фактически его уже дали): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910346/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-search-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE. А я бы с удовольствием принял ответ)

Comment: @muturgan, по поводу MariaDB, на самом деле я немного наврал — там бага и не было — JSON-функции были введены после форка... По поводу возможностей — в чём-то на самом деле отстаёт, а в чём-то обгоняет... например теже JSON-функции появились на пару лет позже, а тип `json` ввели как обычный `LONGTEXT` для совместимости... зато нормальные REGEXP'ы (через pcre) появились уже 5 с лишним лет назад, в то время как в мускуле только недавно (с 8.0.4).