# Как заставить JSON_SEARCH понять, что я ищу число?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

На запрос

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[3]', 'one', 3) as 'index' // в массиве число, ищу число
```

мне отвечают

```
[
    {
      "index": null
    }
]
```

А на запрос

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[\"3\"]', 'one', '3') as 'index' // в массиве строка, ищу строку
```

мне отвечают

```
[
    {
      "index": "\"$[2]\""
    }
]
```

Но на запрос

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[\"3\"]', 'one', 3) as 'index' // в массиве строка, ищу число
```

мне тоже отвечают

```
[
    {
      "index": "\"$[2]\""
    }
]
```

Вопрос - как заставить mysql понять, что я ищу число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то никак. Это [баг](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233) в MySQL, хотя его и *исправили*, добавив в документацию, что аргументом `JSON_SEARCH ()` должна быть строка. За состоянием дел можно следить в [*feature request*](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90085)'е.

В MariaDB данной проблемы нет. Однако различий между числовыми и строковыми значениями также не делается.

---

<sup>По мотивам [Как совместить JSON_REMOVE и JSON_SEARCH в одном запросе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910198/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-remove-%d0%b8-json-search-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5/910280?noredirect=1#comment1498579_910280)</sup>